# theme php contact form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, contacts

I purchased several themes so that I could build two websites.  the theme that I like the most comes with a non-functional contact form.  I have tried to integrate the contact forms from the other themes into it but they will not work no matter what I do.  I know that one of them works fine because I am using it on another site and it works with no issue. (for transparency the working form is being used in the theme that it came with.) is there a possibility that I am missing something?
I've copied and pasted the exact forms into the theme site and included the Js files that deal with the contact form and all I can get are errors when I try to test it live.
this is the code for the form:

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="title-normal">Contact Form</h3>
                        <form id="contact-form" action="contact-form.php" method="post" role="form">
                            <div class="error-container"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" type="text" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" type="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Subject</label>
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-subject" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control form-control-message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="" rows="10" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right"><br>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary solid blank" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

this is a copy of the php:

```
<?php

//Add your information here
$recipient = "info@domain.us";

//Don't edit anything below this line

//import form information
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$name=stripslashes($name);
$email=stripslashes($email);
$subject=stripslashes($subject);
$message=stripslashes($message);
$message= "Name: $name, Subject: $subject \n\n Message: $message";

/*
Simple form validation
check to see if an email and message were entered
*/

//if no message entered and no email entered print an error
if (empty($message) && empty($email)){
print "No email address and no message was entered. <br>Please include an email and a message";
}
//if no message entered send print an error
elseif (empty($message)){
print "No message was entered.<br>Please include a message.<br>";
}
//if no email entered send print an error
elseif (empty($email)){
print "No email address was entered.<br>Please include your email. <br>";
}


//mail the form contents
if(mail("$recipient", "$subject", "$message", "From: $email" )) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in">
        <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "alert" aria-hidden = "true">&times;</button>
    
        <p>Email Sent Successfully! We Will get back to you shortly</p></div>';

    } else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

    }
```

here is the Js
$('#contact-form').submit(function(){

```
  var $form = $(this),
     $error = $form.find('.error-container'),
     action  = $form.attr('action');

  $error.slideUp(750, function() {
     $error.hide();

     var $name = $form.find('.form-control-name'),
        $email = $form.find('.form-control-email'),
        $subject = $form.find('.form-control-subject'),
        $message = $form.find('.form-control-message');

     $.post(action, {
           name: $name.val(),
           email: $email.val(),
           subject: $subject.val(),
           message: $message.val()
        },
        function(data){
           $error.html(data);
           $error.slideDown('slow');

           if (data.match('success') != null) {
              $name.val('');
              $email.val('');
              $subject.val('');
              $message.val('');
           }
        }
     );

  });

  return false;
```

});

Comment: Please post the javascript code. Is the form handled 100% with javascript?

Comment: Make sure the web host supports sending an email. Also, the ``mail`` function doesn't work on localhost

Comment: @OMiShah - "Also, the mail function doesn't work on localhost" - It will work perfectly fine as long as you've configured it correctly. Just because it's localhost doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: here is the JS for the contact form

Comment: To display errors, use these lines on top of your php code

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

also mail() is not supported for most of the hosting vendors. do consider using php-mailer with SMTP or SendGrid.